# How do I merge 2 python dictionaries in R?

Tags: r, dictionary, reticulate

I am using the Tensorflow package in R, and I need to merge 2 dictionaries to create a single feed.dict.

In python [this is simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression). What is the best way to get this done in R? For reasons out of my control, I cannot use Python directly.

**EDIT**

I have come up with the following work around. If anyone has a better solution please post an answer.

```
mergeDictionaries = function(dict1, dict2){
  list1 = py_to_r(dict1)
  list2 = py_to_r(dict2)
  r_to_py(c(list1, list2))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newly created [reticulate](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate) package which provides an R interface to python modules can be used in your case. Assuming that you have Python 3 installed, you can run the following code chunk,

```
py_str = "x = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
y = {'b':10, 'c': 11}
z = dict(list(x.items()) + list(y.items()))"


py_dict = reticulate::py_run_string(code = py_str, local = FALSE, convert = FALSE)
py_dict$z
```

The result will be,

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 10, 'c': 11}
```